# Display an alert box in php and navigate back

Tags: javascript, php

I want to display a javascript alert box in php and navigate back to the main page. Here is my code

```
    session_start();
    $name= $_SESSION['name'];
             $id= $_SESSION['id'];
            //check if is a guest 
            if($name=="Guest"){
        echo'<script type="text/javascript">alert(" You are not allowed to view this contnent"); </script>';
        header('Location: mainPage.php');
    }
    //the rest of my page
```

With this code the alert popup is not displayed only the redirection. I also try this

```
$name= $_SESSION['name'];
    $id= $_SESSION['id'];
    //check if is a guest 
    if($name=="Guest"){

        echo'<script type="text/javascript">window.alert(" You are not allowed to view this contnent");</script>';
        echo'<script type="text/javascript> window.navigate("mainPage.php"); </script>';

    }
            //the rest of my page
```

Now the popup is displayed but the redirection does not work.

Answer (score 0):

try this.Just add after how many seconds the page need to redirect . so

change

```
header('Location: mainPage.php');
```

to

```
header( "refresh:5; url=mainPage.php" );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$name= $_SESSION['name'];
    $id= $_SESSION['id'];
    //check if is a guest 
    if($name=="Guest"){

        echo'<script type="text/javascript">window.alert(" You are not allowed to view this contnent");</script>';
        echo'<script type="text/javascript> window.location.href="mainPage.php"; </script>';

    }
```

please review this code

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
$name = $_SESSION['name'];
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
//check if is a guest 
if($name=="Guest"){
    echo'<script type="text/javascript">
           alert(" You are not allowed to view this contnent");  
           self.location="mainPage.php"; 
         </script>';

}
```

Try this